# Xcode plist not loading

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to store some strings in a Plist, then pick a random one and display it on a label.  Xcode is unable to find or load the Plist for some reason.

The code "NSLog(@"dictionary: %@, array: %@", plistDict, plistArray);"

Returns "2013-07-29 11:38:22.216 Random[1434:60b] dictionary: (null), array: (null)"

So I can only assume this means the .plist file is invalid, or Xcode is unable to read it for some reason.  Here is my .m code for the button:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:
                  @"jokes" ofType:@"plist"];

NSDictionary *plistDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSMutableArray *plistArray = plistDict[@"list"];

int randV = arc4random() % plistArray.count;

jokeLabel.text = plistArray[randV];

NSLog(@"dictionary: %@, array: %@", plistDict, plistArray);
```

Also, here is what my plist file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>list</key>
    <array>
        <string>Some Text Here</string>
        <string>Other Text Here</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

What would I need to do to make this work properly?  Thanks!

Comment: Make sure the file is added to the target. Log the path you get from the bundle.

Answer (score 0):

What's the value of NSString *path?  If that's null, then everything else will be to.
Your filename is going to be case sensitive, so check that the plist is called "jokes.plist"

Answer (score 0):

Your code is absolutely fine. Check whether the plist file added to the project has the correct name.